# Custom allocator sometimes crashes with stl vector

Tags: c++, stl, allocator

I've been given a custom allocator that implements it's own allocation policies, its own malloc/free, etc. Now, I've been asked to use this custom allocator with a STL container (being it a vector or some other). I've created a class, say `my_stdAllocator`, that is an interface compliant to the *ISO C++ standard*. through this class I call my allocator's methods. For example:

```
template <class T>
class my_stdAllocator {

    // ...other required stuff...

    // allocate 'num' elements of type T
    pointer allocate(size_type num, const_pointer = 0) {
        return static_cast<T*>(MYAllocator::instance()->malloc(num));
    }

    // deallocate memory at 'p'
    void deallocate(pointer p, size_type num=0) { 
        MYAllocator::instance()->free(p);
    }

    // initialize allocated memory at 'p' with value 'value'
    void construct(pointer p, const T& value) {   
        ::new ((void*)p) T(value);  
    }


    // destroy elements of initialized memory at p
    void destroy(pointer p) {
        p->~T();
    }

    // ...other required stuff...

} // end my_stdAllocator
```

The custom allocator normally works like a charm: it has been extensively tested, it definitely improves performances, limits fragmentation, etc. When I use it as the allocator for a stl container, (say, a vector) it has this weird behaviour in that it sometimes works properly, while it crashes with a segfault error some other times.

To give an example, it properly allocates and frees with a vector of `char`:

```
typedef char TP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

std::vector<TP, my_stdAllocator<TP> > vec;

std::string s ("Whatever string, no matter how long...");

std::string::iterator it;
for (it=s.begin(); it<s.end(); ++it)
    vec.push_back(*it);

...
```

It is ok when pushing "by hand" numbers inside the vector

```
typedef double TP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

std::vector<TP, my_stdAllocator<TP> > vec;

// "manual" push_back
vec.push_back(3.2);
vec.push_back(6.4);
vec.push_back(9.6);
vec.push_back(12.8);
vec.push_back(15.1);
vec.push_back(18.3);
vec.push_back(21.5);

...
```

It halts with a Segmentation fault when inserting elements through a loop:

```
typedef int TP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

std::vector<TP, ff_stdAllocatorInst<TP> > vec;

for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    vec.push_back( (TP) i );

...
```

It works like a charm when reserving space for *at least* a certain number of elements:

```
typedef int TP;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { 

std::vector<TP, ff_stdAllocatorInst<TP> > vec;

vec.reserve(size);
for(unsigned int i=0; i<size+150; ++i)
    vec.push_back( (TP) i );

...
```

Notice that, the segfault mentioned above doesn't happen when using a *placement new* like this one:

```
void *p = MYAllocator::instance()->malloc(size);
std::vector<TP> *vec = new (p) std::vector<TP>
for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; ++i)
    vec->push_back( (TP) i );

...
```

As I've said already, the custom allocator has been tested and works fine. My class is a simple interface between C++ standard and the custom allocator. I've tried to debug it wth gdb but it didn't help: the underlying allocator is ok, there must be some mistakes in my code but I cannot understand what is wrong!

Comment: A tool such as `valgrind` is incredibly useful when working with custom allocators; in this case, it probably would've shown that in the cases where things break you're writing to memory which you didn't allocate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your call to your custom allocator's `malloc` function, you need to multiply by the size of the object you're allocating:

```
pointer allocate(size_type num, const_pointer = 0) {
    return static_cast<T*>(MYAllocator::instance()->malloc(num*sizeof(T)));
}
```